# Understanding T-SQL GOTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, goto

My teacher recently talked about the statement 'GOTO', to be used in Management Studio, but I didn't quite understand it at first. He stated that GOTO is being used to jump to different pieces of code, with the help of a label I can name by myself. This is the code he used to represent his example:

```
select 'first'

goto jump
select 'second'

jump:
select 'third'
```

When I execute the code, sure enough, it prints 'first' and 'third'. My question now is what was the select 'second' doing there in the first place?

Comment: `GOTO` is a way to control the flow of your query.  In practical use, there would be a condition that you would need to satisfy (e.g.: `IF SomeCol = 'SomeValue' GOTO jump`) for the `GOTO`.  In the example provided, the only use of the `SELECT 'second'` is to illustrate that when you use `GOTO`, that code is skipped over.

Comment: As to why it's there in the first place this is a bad example.  A better example would be: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx In this case instead of embedding code within the if, you use goto to call the code.  This has the advantage if multiple if statements could call the same goto, of refactoring the code for easier readability; and less copy/pasting.  However most people would instead create a function/procedure with the necessary code and call it; which is why GoTo isn't a popular choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the second `select` is clearly unnecessary.

`GOTO` is an example of "control-flow" for the the program code.  It is a construct from the earliest computer languages, one that maps directly onto how the hardware works when processing languages such as C or assembly code.  Since then, it has been included in many other languages.

`GOTO` would often be used with `IF`.  However, T-SQL offers better control flow functionality, such as:

- WHILE
- IF/BEGIN
- TRY/CATCH

In general, you should be using these constructs and not `GOTO`.  In fact, `GOTO` is rather controversial.  Many people think it is always a sign of poor code ("spaghetti code" is sometimes used to describe this type of code).  Others will make a very rare exception for something like exception handling (which I sometimes do) or some types of state machines.

In my opinion, `GOTO` should only be taught after all the other constructs and only for very specific purposes.