# Performance Issue due to GOTO statement

Tags: sql-server, database-project

I'm using SQL Server 2016 database project and my script is like below

```
DECLARE Marker NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT Value FROM Table1 WHERE name = 'Marker') 
IF( IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF @Marker = 'Marker1' GOTO Marker2;
    IF @Marker = 'Marker2' GOTO Marker3;
    IF @Marker = 'Marker3' GOTO Marker4;
    IF @Marker = 'Marker4' GOTO Marker5;
    IF @Marker = 'Marker5' GOTO Marker6;
    IF @Marker = 'Marker6' GOTO Marker7;        
    ELSE GOTO EmptyBlock;    
END 

MARKER1:
Code for marker 1

MARKER2:
Code for marker 2    

MARKER3:
Code for marker 3
.
.
.
EmptyBlock:
PRINT 'No changes'
```

This script file will be executed after every deployment and based on deployment it will be skipping the previous lines and now it will be reached to **marker 15**.

It's taking too much time to execute even though there are few lines of code, I've finally found the issue due to **GOTO statements**. I don't know if using GOTO is best practice or not, if its not good practice using it in production site then please give me the suggestions for an alternate of GOTO.

Comment: How do you know the `goto` statement is the issue? It seems very unlikely the `goto` itself would cause an issue, more likely the code that gets run under a given branch.

Comment: I've executed it manually by removing the goto statements then it will be executed less time, It seems very unlikely the goto itself would cause an issue  => don't know the if it is causing an issue or not because until now it will work fine when deployment but taking the time and will be increased along with marker :(

Comment: Your best bet is to inspect (and then post) the execution plan.

Comment: The way you have written it in the question, if the code jumps to `MARKER` then its also going to execute `MARKER2`, `MARKER2` and so on. is that really how your code looks?

Comment: yes it is a new site then it will be executed from start

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown which would cause a performance issue. Under normal circumstances GOTO will be very fast, its not like it has to do anything. So whatever is causing the performance issue is related to the code as a whole, and therefore we need to see the execution plan (which is an essential part of any performance question).

Comment: In terms of best practice see this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046017/sql-goto-statement)

Comment: [And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453903/understanding-t-sql-goto)

Comment: Thank you @DaleK, by your suggestions one thing will be clarified " GOTO " is worst coding and will be used if there is no alternative

Comment: can you please suggest me a way to solve this problem

Comment: Bad coding practice doesn't mean its slow. Anyway you have an answer below - have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the [`GOTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql) statements with a script like this using [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql):

```
-- get the number of the marker (instead of the full name of the marker).
DECLARE @Marker INT = (SELECT REPLACE(Value, 'Marker', '') FROM Table1 WHERE name = 'Marker')

IF @Marker IS NULL
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'no marker'
  END
IF @Marker < 1
  BEGIN
    -- Code for Marker No. 1
  END
IF @Marker < 2
  BEGIN
    -- Code for Marker No. 2
  END
IF @Marker < 3
  BEGIN
    -- Code for Marker No. 3
  END
IF @Marker < 4
  BEGIN
    -- Code for Marker No. 4
  END
ELSE IF @Marker IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'no changes'
  END
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4984fa273730e6809c489aa01c060f33)

Comment: You’re missing a bunch of ELSE statements. If you assume that was the op’s intent, you should note that in the answer.